# What is this metal bookcase component called?

Tags: bolts

I have partially assembled a tree bookcase and have discovered that I have been supplied with an incorrect part.  I was supplied with the part shown in the attached picture.  The pictured part is 76mm in length, yet the assembly requires the same but at 71mm.  I have contacted the vendor, who do not know the part's name, but assure me that I can find them in any hardware store.  No hardware store I have visited has been able to identify it, though.

Please, can somebody tell me what is the name of the part, and where can I find one that at 71mm?

Thanks.

[image]

Comment: 1. What does it connect to? That'll help in identifying/naming it. 2. Are you sure you need a shorter one? Do you think you need 71mm because the instructions say so? - It could be a misprint. Or because you can't make it fit properly? - Maybe you're assembling it wrong.

Comment: It is used to join the top (heavy) half of a bookcase to its bottom.  The two pieces are to be joined end to end.  The instructions state that a 71mm connector is required.  Inserting the connector reveals that it is 5mm away from sitting flush.

Comment: Sorry, I wasn't clear enough. Rather than what it connects (two parts of a bookcase), I want to know what other components it connects *to*. i.e. Does it connect to a [cam](https://www.google.co.uk/search?tbm=isch&source=hp&biw=770&bih=742&ei=02iFWtnfM861gQbgipn4AQ&q=cam+connector&oq=cam+conn&gs_l=img.3.0.0l7.936.2340.0.3485.9.9.0.0.0.0.80.373.8.8.0....0...1ac.1.64.img..1.8.372.0..0i10k1.0.QMdp8Vp8hD0) at both ends? Something else?

Comment: My fault, entirely! And yes, it connects to a cam.  I believe that the shorter one might work, so I'll give it a try. Thanks again

Comment: what do the assembly instructions call it?

Comment: IKEA calls it a `cam-lock pin` ... https://www.furnitureparts.com/search?q=cam%20lock%20pin&hPP=12&idx=shopify_products&p=0&type=product&is_v=1

Comment: no, it's definitely a double emded cam dowel

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm tempted to call that a double-ended dowel for a cam connection.

Comment: Thank you.  It seems that they're readily available...in 68mm.

Comment: That's frustrating! Maybe you could use the shorter one, and re-drill the hole for the cam? It wouldn't be as strong though, as the original hole will mostly overlap with the new hole. And it would look a bit bodged too, if it was visible.

Comment: If the one that's 5 mm too long isn't close enough, 2 mm too short isn't likely to work either. Recutting the hole 2 mm shallower is likely to be a lot weaker; I'd feel safer with the too-long piece and a spacer -- or a web search for the elusive 71 mm part.